# Animating a custom list view

Tags: android, android-animation

I have searched the forum for this , but found no similar question, okay so I have a customised list view, Each entry in this list is a text view and an image. Suppose the user adds the text in some activity.and presses the save button. When pressing the back button to come back to this list view. The entry just added should swipe in from the right.How can I do that, any example would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one working example from bottom to top, I guess you can turn that into right to left ;-)

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        //Do the animation once.    
        if (position > maxposition) {
            AnimationSet set = new AnimationSet(true);

            Animation animation = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
            animation.setDuration(400);
            set.addAnimation(animation);

            animation = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
                    0.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 1.0f,
                    Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.0f);
            animation.setDuration(500);
            set.addAnimation(animation);

            row.startAnimation(set);
            maxposition = position;
        } 

        return row;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks guys,interpolators helped me a lot, but thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your contribution, I did some more digging, and found that interpolators provide animations to views. Referred an example, implemented it and got what I wanted.